# Почему при установке Laravel через composer дополнительно устанавливаются 75 каких то плагинов, от Symphony и прочее?

Tags: laravel, composer

75 дополнительных программ для голого Laravel Это нормально??[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel написан не на чистом PHP. Поэтому необходимые для работы компоненты указаны в зависимостях и потому composer при установке их тянет из сети. Так, что всё нормально.

Answer (score 2):

laravel написан на symfony и использует кучу сторонних плагинов, чтобы вам было удобно работать с фреймворком из коробки